# rsuffix for merging data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have multiple dataframes with the same columns but different values that look like that

[Product 1 Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Febh1.png)

Here's the code that generated them

```
    import pandas as pd 
    
    d1 = {"Year":[2018,2019,2020],"Quantity": [10,20,30], "Price": [100,200,300]}
    df_product1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
    
    d2 = {"Year":[2018,2019,2020],"Quantity": [20,20,50], "Price": [120,110,380]}
    df_product2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
    
    d3 = {"Year":[2018,2019,2020],"Quantity": [40,20,70], "Price": [1000,140,380]}
    df_product3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)
```

I merge two dataframes and identify suffixes like so

```
df_total = df_product1.merge(df_product2,on="Year", suffixes = ("_Product1","_Product2"))
```

And I get

[First Merged Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLEbu.png)

However, when I merge another dataframe to the result above using:

```
  df_total = df_total.merge(df_product3,on="Year", suffixes = ("_Product","_Product3"))
```

I get

[Final Merged Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSD4u.png)

Where there is no suffix for the third product.

I would like the last two columns of the dataframe to be Quantity_Product3, Price_Product3 instead of just Quantity and Price.

Let me know if it is possible or if I need to approach the problem from a completely different angle.

Comment: kindly share sample dataframes with expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy I edited my question and added sample dataframes

Comment: It is generally good practice to share some code which generates the data for a toy example, so people can play around with it.

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you don't get the result you want

It's explained in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

> suffixeslist-like, default is (“_x”, “_y”) A length-2 sequence where
> each element is optionally a string indicating the suffix to add to
> **overlapping** column names in left and right respectively. Pass a value
> of None instead of a string to indicate that the column name from left
> or right should be left as-is, with no suffix. At least one of the
> values must not be None.

Suffixes are added to **overlapping** column names.

See this example - suffixes are added to column b, because both dataframes have a column b, but not to columns a and c, as they are unique and not in common between the two dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns =['a','b'], data = np.random.rand(10,2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns =['b','c'], data = np.random.rand(10,2), index = np.arange(5,15))

# equivalent to an inner join on the indices
out = pd.merge(df1, df2, how ='inner', left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

### A crude solution

Why don't you just rename the columns manually? Not elegant but effective

### A possible alternative

The table you are trying to build looks like a pivot. I would look into normalising all your dataframes, concatenating them, then running a pivot on the result.

Depending on your case, this may well be more convoluted and could well be overkill. I mention it because I want to bring your attention to the concepts of pivoting/unpivoting (stacking/unstacking/normalising) data.

The code below takes a df which looks similar to yours and normalises it. For simpler cases you can use pandas.melt(). I don't have the exact data of your example but this should be a good starting point.

```
def random_dates(start, end, n, unit='D', seed=None):
    ndays = (end - start).days + 1
    return start + pd.to_timedelta(
        np.random.randint(0, ndays, n), unit=unit
    )
    

df = pd.DataFrame()
mysize = 20
df['key'] = np.arange(0,mysize)

df['A_value'] = np.random.randint(0,10000,mysize)
df['A_date'] = random_dates(pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01' ), pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01'), mysize)

df['B_value'] = np.random.randint(-5000,5000,mysize)
df['B_date'] = random_dates(pd.to_datetime('2005-01-01' ), pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'), mysize)

df['C_value'] = np.random.randint(-10000,10000,mysize)
df['C_date'] = random_dates(pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01' ), pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01'), mysize)

df2 = df.set_index('key', drop=True,  verify_integrity = True)
df2 = df2.stack().reset_index()

df2.columns=['key','rawsource','rawvalue']

df2['source'] = df2['rawsource'].apply(lambda x: x[0:1])
df2['metric'] = df2['rawsource'].apply(lambda x: x[2:])
df2 = df2.drop(['rawsource'], axis = 1)

df_piv = df2.pivot_table( index=['key','source'], columns = 'metric' , values ='rawvalue', aggfunc='first' ).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did think about how to pivot it but haven't figured it out. However, I have used the proposed crude solution and wrote a simple function that renames the merged columns by appending the product name. Thanks!